# Editing file in bundle, objective c

Tags: objective-c, bundle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Writing into a file objective c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5853014/writing-into-a-file-objective-c)

in my application i've a xml file and a sql file in the bundle of the app, i drop them in Resource folder.

I want to edit the in my app, i need to put them on Documentens folder on first startup?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your target: iOS or Mac OS? Is it an application to be sold at the App Store?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can't modify anything in the app bundle -- you must first copy it to a writeable directory, usually the app's Documents folder.

Comment: Technically, it is possible. Applications that are not targeted to the App Store shouldn’t be subject to this limitation.